# How do I iterate over a set to list all the keys?

Tags: redis

I'm trying to loop through all the keys in my set but not sure how this works.

Say I have a set like this:

```
SADD myset "hello" "world"
```

My set now has 2 keys in it.

How can I loop through and get all the values, or page through them?

I tried this:

```
$redis.scan(0, match:"myset")
```

and I get this back:

```
2.3.3 :020 > $redis.scan(0, match:"myset")
 => ["0", ["myset"]]
```

I'm confused as to what to do with that result?

Comment: I don't know redis. But maybe you can loop n times, n being the cardinality of the set (seems to be scard command). Ruby loop would be `n.times do end`. Then with redis `redis.scard("myset").to_i.times do ... end` very just a guess though...

Comment: First, try to avoid global variables like `$redis` when doing Ruby. Those can backfire on you in a huge way, as with global variables in general. Steer towards instance variables like `@redis` or methods that return handles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`SMEMBERS`](https://redis.io/commands/smembers) command to get all set members:

```
$redis.smembers('myset')
```

If you're looking to scan through and match then you need to use the [`SSCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/sscan) variant:

```
$redis.sscan('myset', 0, match: '...')
```

Comment: I want to use scan because my set may have thousands of keys.

Comment: That's what `SSCAN` is for.